# Fast columnwise python numpy operation depending on columwise condition

Tags: python, numpy

So I got a matrix looking something like

```
0.8, 0.7,nan,...
0.1,nan,0.1,...
0.9,nan,0.3,...
```

with dimensions N X M, where M >> N

Now I want to go through all columns and change the values of the matrix as follows:

1. If the column has exactly K values >= 0, do nothing
2. If the column has L < K values >= 0, set K-L values of this column to X
3. If the column has S > K values >= 0, set S-K values of this column to nan

I am looking for a fast way to do this with python for a large optimization and my for loop is taking too long still.

The outcome in the above example, with K = 2, should look like:

```
0.8, 0.7,nan,...
0.1,X,0.1,...
nan, nan,0.3,...
```

What I am considering at the moment is first sorting each column of the entire matrix (I have to restore the previous order later though) and to somehow apply np.where(num_cols != K,applyChanges(myMat),myMat), but I am not sure how to make np.where return me the columns of the matrix and not the invidivual scalars.

Thanks for any suggestion :)

edit:
So I was able to speed up my code by a factor of slightly more than 5 by first using argsort on the columns. This was I could directly set the appropriate values without requiring anyfurther "argwhere" calls which made my previous code slow.

All I can do now seems to be to move from numpy arrays to python lists as I now do a for loop and access the elements directly which is faster done using lists.

edit2:
Using numba's @jit decorator I was able to increase the speed again by a factor of 5. Wow, I am impressed, pretty cool library (is that even the proper term for it?). Now my code is fast enough for my current requirements.

edit3:
As requested, here is my for loop, it is straight forward

```
idx_sorted = np.argsort(pred_new, axis=0)
num_bands_selected = np.sum(pred_new >= 0, axis=0)

for idx_col in range(0, num_cols):
    if num_bands_selected[idx_col] < N:
        pred_new[idx_sorted[num_bands_selected[idx_col]-N:, idx_col], idx_col] = dummy_value
    elif num_bands_selected[idx_col] > N:
        pred_new[idx_sorted[-num_bands_selected[idx_col]:-N, idx_col], idx_col] = np.nan
```

pred_new is something a neural network returns, but the data has to be in a specific format for some postprocessing algorithm to work.

This could be sped up to the best of my knowledge in two ways (aside from the @jit which was not included):

1. Using python lists instead of numpy arrays (they allow faster read access)
2. First selecting columns that require modification. Here I go through everything, but often only some subset (~50 %) might require modification

Comment: maybe you can provide your for loop

Comment: Included it in my edit